# How do I access data from a dictionary in a HTML template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, html-templates

When I try to use data from a dictionary, I get the error:

`'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'`

This happens when I click on a link that should take me to the page of the entry. The entry is a Markdown file that I get from `util.get_entry(title)`.

How do I access data from a dictionary in my HTML template (`entry.html`)? Do I need to convert the Markdown into HTML?

entry.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

<!-- {% load static %} -->

{% block title %}
{{ name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block style %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="left">{{ entry }}</div>
<div class="right">
    <a href="{% url 'edit' %}">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from . import util

def entry(request, name):
    if util.get_entry(name) is not None:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/entry.html'), {
            'entry': util.get_entry(name),
            'name': name
        }
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/404.html")
```

urls.py:

```
path('<str:name>', views.entry, name='entry'),
```

util.py:

```
def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Comment: Share util, there might be error. It should work like `entry.html` if `entry` is a dict and `html` is a key inside it.

Comment: @NixonSparrow  I have added util.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the dict in parameters. Please use this

```
from . import util

def entry(request, name):
    if util.get_entry(name) is not None:
        context ={ 
            'entry': util.get_entry(name),
            'name': name

        }
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/entry.html',context)
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/404.html")
```

Comment: So I need to have a dictionary assigned to a variable before I return it?

Comment: Not always, but in this case it helps because one of your values has a function call. If you assign it to a variable first it means the function is evaluated to provide the value for the 'entry' key. Otherwise the function itself, not its result, is passed as context, and the template chokes.